# remove and insert smartcard using sunpkcs#11 and tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, smartcard, pkcs#11

I have a web application running on `Tomcat`. My application uses a web service which signs (via **smartcard**) and sends email. The web service itself adds the `sunpkcs#11` provider automatically during the first call and before sending email, then can sign in and send emails if **smartcard** is not removed and inserted. If removed and inserted, in order to send email I must restart the tomcat server or it will give several errors depending on my code:

```
result= api.signAndSend(to, cc, bcc, subject, content, smartCardPin);
```

After removing and inserting smart card this code gives below exception message:

> Token has been removed

These are my tryings:

1. I tried removing the `sunpkcs#11` provider just after sending email and creating a new `sunpkcs#11` provider and adding it.it gives and error like:

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this
>   key: sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11PrivateKey or
>   java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this
>   key: null

2. I did not remove sunpkcs#11 provider after each api.signAndSend(...) call,

rather :

```
  result= api.signAndSend(to, cc, bcc, subject, content, smartCardPin);  
  SunPKCS11 sunPKCS11=(SunPKCS11)getLastProvider();  
  sunPKCS11.logout();  
  sunPKCS11.setCallbackHandler(new MyCallbackHandler());  
  KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection cpprotection = new KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection(  
  new MyCallbackHandler());  
  KeyStore.Builder builder = KeyStore.Builder.newInstance(  
  "PKCS11", sunPKCS11, cpprotection);  
  KeyStore ks = builder.getKeyStore();  

//finalize PKCS#11  
Field moduleMapField = PKCS11.class.getDeclaredField("moduleMap");  
  moduleMapField.setAccessible(true);  
  Map<?, ?> moduleMap = (Map<?, ?>) moduleMapField.get(null);  
  moduleMap.clear(); // force re-execution of C_Initialize next time  

//load PKCS#11(i expect this code to load pkcs#11 again but i am not sure)  
Method getInstanceMethod = PKCS11.class.getMethod("getInstance",  
  String.class, String.class, CK_C_INITIALIZE_ARGS.class,  
  Boolean.TYPE);  
  CK_C_INITIALIZE_ARGS ck_c_initialize_args = new CK_C_INITIALIZE_ARGS();  
  PKCS11 pkcs11 = (PKCS11) getInstanceMethod.invoke(null, pkcs11Path,  
  "C_GetFunctionList", ck_c_initialize_args, false);
```

this code gives:

> java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed
>         at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Signature.initialize(P11Signature.java:319)
>         at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Signature.engineInitSign(P11Signature.java:432)
>         at java.security.Signature$Delegate.init(Signature.java:1127)
>         at java.security.Signature$Delegate.chooseProvider(Signature.java:1087)
>         at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineInitSign(Signature.java:1151)
>         at java.security.Signature.initSign(Signature.java:512)
>         at org.esign.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
>       .
>       .
>       .
>       Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_KEY_HANDLE_INVALID
>         at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_SignInit(Native Method)
>         at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11$SynchronizedPKCS11.C_SignInit(PKCS11.java:1721)
>         at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Signature.initialize(P11Signature.java:311)

**java: 1.8.0.31**

edit:
i remove and add SunPkcs#11 like this:

```
//the code below adds sunpkcss provider automatically after first call
result= api.signAndSend(to, cc, bcc, subject, content, smartCardPin);

//after each signAndSend i remove sunpkcs and add a new one
String sunpkcs11Name=getLastProvider().getName();
Security.removeProvider(sunpkcs11Name);

String cfg = MessageFormat.format(
                "name = Starcos-SunPkcs11  library = c:/windows/system32/aetpkss1.dll slot = 52481 ");
        InputStream is=new ByteArrayInputStream(cfg.getBytes());

SunPKCS11 newSunPkcs11Provider = new SunPKCS11(is);
Security.addProvider(newSunPkcs11Provider);
```

after i add a new SunPkcs11, while `api.signAndSend(...)` it gives:

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: >sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11PrivateKey

This exception is not because of absence of SunPkcs11 because i see the SunPkcs11 that i added, in the providers list.

Comment: Please share code sample how do you implement remove and add provider approach, acording to my reading this approach should be worked.

Comment: @ihsanAfter addProvider(newSunPkcs11Provider) can you try to get it with name to be sure you succesfully add it getProvider http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Security.html#getProvider(java.lang.String)

Comment: yes i can get it by Security.getProvider(providerName).

Comment: Did you check this link https://community.oracle.com/thread/1528517?

Comment: I checked and even tried it but  that way is for applications that treats PKCS#11 tokens as static keystores as your link in your answer says.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to find exact solution in this kind of problem because it is hard to reproduce it so according to my reading PKCS#11 is already cover this **Smartcards being inserted and removed** scenario according to its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html#AppDev),

> This is fine for an application that treats PKCS#11 tokens as static
>   keystores. For an application that wants to accommodate PKCS#11 tokens
>   more dynamically, such as Smartcards being inserted and removed, you
>   can use the new KeyStore.Builder class. Here is an example of how to
>   initialize the builder for a PKCS#11 keystore with a callback handler.

You already mention that remove and add provider is not working for you but according to this [post](https://securehomes.esat.kuleuven.be/~decockd/wiki/bin/view.cgi/EidForums/ForumEidCardMiddleware0039) they solve it via this way.